# How to specify yaml file to use secret as intended?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I am reading Core Kubernetes by Vyas and Love. Section 8.3.1 has the following 2 yaml files.  Let's call them `secret.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  val1: YXNkZgo=
  val2: YXNkZjIK
stringData:
  val1: asdf
```

and `secret-pod.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysecretpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: myval
      mountPath: /etc/myval
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: myval
    secret:
      secretName: val1
```

When I run `kubectl apply -f secret-pod.yaml`, it errors out.  Using `describe`, I can see this:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age              From               Message
  ----     ------       ----             ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    3s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mysecretpod to minikube
  Warning  FailedMount  0s (x4 over 3s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "myval" : secret "val1" not found
```

This kinda makes sense.  Using `kubectl get secrets`, I can only see the following:

```
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-vhllg   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      5d3h
mysecret              Opaque                                2      19m
```

So I make the following change to `secret-pod.yaml`:

```
  volumes:
  - name: myval
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
```

That makes `kubectl` happy and it promptly creates `mysecretpod` without any issue.  However looking into that pod using `kubectl exec -it mysecretpod -- ls -l /etc/myval`, I get:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Dec 12 08:08 val1 -> ..data/val1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Dec 12 08:08 val2 -> ..data/val2
```

So the content of `mysecret` is loaded into that folder with `val1` and `val2` being files.  I think the authors intend to mount `val1` to be the `/etc/myval` files in that pod.  How should `secret-pod.yaml` be written to achieve that?  I have tried this but it fails:

```
  volumes:
  - name: myval
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret/val1
```

Also, why am I seeing the extraneous  `-> ..data/val...` for both `val1` and `val2`?  What are they?

Comment: So you need to pass the keys to pods, right?

Comment: I need to pass `val1` to the pod.  They want to illustrate that `myval` can be rotated periodically with `val1` and `val2`.

Comment: So are you going to set the secret for the volume? What are you going to use the secrets for? Are they env variables or what?

Comment: The secret is created by the `secret.yaml` file and not environment variables.  I am just following the book, and try to make it work as they intend to.

Answer (score 1):

So for it to work as intended, `secret-pod.yaml` must specify `subPath` as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysecretpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: myval
      mountPath: /etc/myval
      subPath: myval
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: myval
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
      items:
      - key: val1
        path: myval
```